# Read from sector on floppy disk

Tags: assembly

```
mov     ah, 0x02                ; read floppy sector function
    mov     al, 1                   ; read 1 sector
    mov     ch, 1                   ; we are reading the second sector past us, so its still on track 1
    mov     cl, 2                   ; sector to read (The second sector)
    mov     dh, 0                   ; head number
    mov     dl, 0                   ; drive number. Remember Drive 0 is floppy drive.
    int     0x13                    ; call BIOS - Read the sector
```

This is example code from: http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev5.html

I don't really understand this part:

```
        mov     ch, 1                   ; we are reading the second sector past us, so its still on track 1
        mov     cl, 2                   ; sector to read (The second sector)
```

Okay, so the first sector is the boot sector (sector 0). Therefore the sector after that is sector 1.

So shouldn't it be?:

```
mov ch, 0       ;First track
mov cl, 1       ;second sector on first track
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sector number is 1-based while track number is 0-based. Int13 is funky like that.

http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_13-2.html

Comment: Thank you! The tutorial didn't mention that. But a quick check on Wikipedia would have solved my confusion. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector